# How to lookup multiple values and sum a total with one formula?

Tags: excel, formula, array-formulas

I cannot seem to figure out how to lookup multiple unique values in a list, find their respective cost, and sum that cost in a single formula.  I'm sure there is something out there that should work but I'm just such a novice..

So for example, I want to sum the cost of the items in the following list:

Item A

Item A

Item B

Item A

Item C

Item C

using data in the following table:

Item A | 10

Item B | 20

Item C | 30

I've also attached a spreadsheet which should show pretty clearly what I'm trying to do:

[Sample Wkbk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/218n7amvr8u1hc2/Sample%20Wkbk.xlsx?dl=0)

Thank You in advance!  :)

Comment: You want to count the cost of each item only once, or as many times as it is repeated?

Comment: As many times as it is repeated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following formula which applies to the attached diagram; adjust it to your actual data layout (where the lists reside).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,A2:A7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into it more in here. 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1705-excel-sum-average-unique-values.html

you can try this? 
 Type this formula: =SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A15,A2:A15&""),A2:A15) into a blank cell, see screenshot:

[image]